# In Umbraco, is there a way to add dictionary fields into a rich text editor?

Tags: dictionary, tinymce, umbraco

I am working on a site that will be using multiple keywords throughout.  We don't want to have  people go through every single page and add in the new info over the old info for every change to these specific values.  I was hoping that the dictionary library in umbraco would be able to help since it is being used in the XSLTSearch but it looks like i would only be able to make a macro that would search for the dictionary item and insert it that way.

is there a way to just insert a field in the rich text editor from the dictionary without just making a macro?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Shortcodes](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/shortcodes) package would meet your needs. It allows you to use the [macro parameter syntax](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/templates/umbracomacro-element/macro-parameters/advanced-macro-parameter-syntax) to place properties in the RTE, templates, or even macros. It also can output the result of a RestExtension/base method.